# How to automatically select *interpretation* buffer window

Tags: compilation-mode, sh-mode

When I am writing a shell script in `sh-mode` and decide to run it, I hit <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> (`executable-interpret`). An `*interpretation*` buffer is displayed, showing the script's output.

Is there a robust way to automatically make this `*interpretation*` buffer current after it pops up, instead of having to type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (`other-window`)?

Comment: @Drew Please review my edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a robust way to automatically make this `*interpretation*` buffer current after it pops up, instead of having to type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (`other-window`)?

There are several ways of varying degree of hackiness to achieve this, but here is my preferred method.

The `*interpretation*` buffer is created by the command `executable-interpret`, bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> by default in `sh-mode`, whose docstring reads:

```
executable-interpret is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
function in ‘executable.el’.

(executable-interpret COMMAND)

Run script with user-specified args, and collect output in a buffer.
While script runs asynchronously, you can use the C-x `
command to find the next error.  The buffer is also in ‘comint-mode’ and
‘compilation-shell-minor-mode’, so that you can answer any prompts.
```

The key clue here is `compilation-shell-minor-mode`, which suggests we can hook into settings of the `compile` library. One such relevant setting is `compilation-finish-functions`:

```
compilation-finish-functions is a variable defined in ‘compile.el’.
Its value is nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Functions to call when a compilation process finishes.
Each function is called with two arguments: the compilation buffer,
and a string describing how the process finished.
```

This allows us to register a custom function which selects the `*interpretation*` buffer when the script is done jogging:

```el
(defun my-pop-to-interpretation-buffer (buffer _why)
  "Pop to `*interpretation*' BUFFER.
Intended as an element of `compilation-finish-functions'."
  (when (string-match-p "\\`\\*interpretation\\*\\'" (buffer-name buffer))
    (pop-to-buffer buffer)))

(add-to-list 'compilation-finish-functions #'my-pop-to-interpretation-buffer)
```

You can, of course, modify `my-pop-to-interpretation-buffer` to your heart's content.

Comment: This sounds good. But my first attempt was just to copy&paste the last code snippet to my ~/.emacs.d/init.el doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnGoofy You'll have to update your question with a more precise description than "doesn't work" in order for anyone to be able to help you. Please try to provide a reproducible set of steps starting from `emacs -Q` leading to the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Okay, storing this code snippet in my init.el doesn't work. Where  do I need to store this code?

Comment: @JohnGoofy If you want it to take effect in every Emacs session, then you need to place it in your `user-init-file`. You can also just evaluate it once-off for the current session. Are you sure you are evaluating the code, i.e. adding it to your `user-init-file` and then restarting Emacs?

Comment: Sorry, but I saved this code-snippet via copy&paste into my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, sourced it and even restart my machine but it won't work, nothing happens.

Comment: @JohnGoofy Like I said in my first comment: "it won't work" and "nothing happens" do not provide others with enough information to help you. Please update your question with a precise and reproducible set of steps leading to the undesired behaviour. This recipe should state your Emacs version and list all the commands/keys you invoke starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @JohnGoofy Just to clarify - the code in my answer does not on its own do anything. It customises what happens when you type `C-c C-x` in a `sh-mode` buffer, as you describe in your question. I.e. you need to type `C-c C-x` in a `sh-mode` buffer to see the effects of my suggestion.

Comment: ... I know, I've already tried this in sh-mode, which is normally activated if I open a shell-script. What you do not understand, that your code-snippet do not has any effect if I save it in my init-file? I Still have to type `C-x` `o` to switch to the `*interpretation*`-buffer if I execute the script via `C-c` `C-x`

Comment: @JohnGoofy What I don't understand is **why** my suggestion doesn't work, not **that** it doesn't work. This is why a comment such as "it doesn't work" does not help anyone, and providing a reproducible recipe is crucial. Try starting Emacs with the `-Q` flag and then evaluating my suggested code before invoking `C-c C-x`. If it works, which it should, then some other setting or package you enable in your `user-init-file`, e.g. [`shackle`](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle), is interfering with my suggested customisation.

Comment: @JohnGoofy See also this article about reporting Emacs bugs starting with `-Q`: https://swsnr.de/posts/reproduce-bugs-in-emacs-q.